# getting error when I start toad application

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I am getting this problem when I start TOAD.

The following error has occurred:

> Cannot open file D:\DBASE\TOAD\TEMPS\PLSQLSCR.TXT

How can I resolve this problem? If anyone has an idea please share it with me.

Comment: I'm a bit at a loss as to what sort of answer you're hoping for. I think you need to describe the exact capability you need, and also list all the constraints you're working under, including what system privileges and Toad configurations you are using.

Comment: This is something system related issues.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have an entry in the TOAD startup preference for a file which doesn't exist. So the solution depends on what you want to the tool to do.

If you're expecting it to run a startup script then you need to find the location of the file and change the entry. If you're not expecting it to run anything then you need to remove the file from the preference.

I don't have TOAD to hand (and this may be something which varies according to version and maybe OS) but the pertinent preference is something like:

<kbd>menu</kbd> View -> Toad options -> Schema browser -> Startup